# Render responsive site in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, responsive-design

In my app I have a WebView which is meant to load a local HTML page as if it was a mobile browser. What it actually does is loading the page in the "desktop mode" and if I zoom in it just makes the content bigger instead of wrapping it.

As is (table rendered as multi-column)

[image]

Must be (table rendered as single-column)

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve adding the line

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=200, maximum-scale=200, user-scalable=no" />
```

in the HTML code.

No other setting in Java code seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code in webview to work like a mobile browser in your App

String strCrome = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android-4.0.3; en-us; Xoom Build/IML77) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) CrMo/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7";

Webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(strCrome);
Webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't help anyway.

Comment: If you don't get any proper solution then please add your code so that we can get exactly solution for it.